# Angular 2: An attribute's component value does not show in the html (DOM)) when I looad the page for the first time

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-components

I have a component in Angular 2 that looks like this:

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'gal-tour-summary',
  template: 'Show variable: {{this.testVariable}}', 
  styleUrls: ['./tour-summary.component.css']
})
export class TourSummaryComponent implements OnInit {

  cruise: any;
  itineraries: any;
  testVariable: string; //This is the variable i have created

  constructor(private utils: UtilsService) {
 testVariable = "Why this text does not appearr in my page when the component is loaded??"; //Here, in the constructo, I put some value to my variable, so, it should appear in my html now, right?
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cruise = this.utils.linked['selectedBarco'];
    this.itineraries = this.createIterDay(this.cruise.itinerarios[this.cruise.iterIndex].tipoItinerario.detalleItinerarioList);
    console.log( 'Total de itinerarios: ' + this.itineraries.length );
  }
}
```

The problem is that I'm trying to show the value of the testVariable in the HTML and this just does not work. I have tried everything. What could be the problem here? Has anyone of you had the same problem before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: typo, it should be `string` for testVariable

Comment: remove "this." from variable (also what Queintin said), you should probably post your error message though

Comment: Thanks for your answer, guys! @q

Comment: Hi, @QuentinLaillé. That typo were only in the example I typed here, but in my code was well written. Sorry about that. 

I could solve the problem and it wasn't in this component, but in another one that had an error that I could see in the console, which I guess caused other components not to work properly. 

I'm new to Angular, so I didn't know that an error in another component (which I had already seen before asking this question) could cause other functions or components not to work properly. 

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks, @Laurens! 

I could solve the problem and it wasn't in this component, but in another one that had an error that I could see in the console, which I guess caused other components not to work properly. 

I'm new to Angular, so I didn't know that an error in another component could cause other functions or components not to work properly. 

When you asked me for the error message, I told myself that I propably should solve that error  first (in another component) so I could see if that could solve the problem in my component and it was like this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It may sounds stupid and obvious, but I guess this could be helpful for people new to Angular and Web Development.

My component was ok! But in the JS console, I could see that there were an error in another component. Solving this issue (in another component) my application started working properly.

What I learned here, is that an error in a component, could make others components and functions not to work properly. Thanks for those who answered the question.